# Android: 2.1 AND install on SD-card feature for 2.2+ users

Tags: android, eclipse, backwards-compatibility

I want my Android application to support 2.1 (Eclair), but I also want it to support installation to sd-card for 2.2 (and later) users.
I'm using MOTODEV, and I created a new 2.1 project. I tried adding    `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` to my manifest file, but it doesn't work because it's not supported in 2.1. How can i make my application support SD-installation **and** at the same time support 2.1?

**EDIT:** I see I can use `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` even for 2.1 and older builds according to http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html#Compatiblity. The trick is, as *CommonsWare* stated below, to change the build target to 2.2.

The problem now is that Eclipse/Motodev won't let me run or debug on virtual devices that are older than the build. It simply doesn't list the device. I tried tricking it by changing the build target, choosing an older device in run/debug configurations, and then changing build target back, but I just got the following message in the console:

Preferred AVD 'eclair_hvga' is not compatible with the project target 'Android 2.2'. Looking for a compatible AVD...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your *build* target (Android section of project properties in MOTODEV Studio for Android) to 2.2. This causes you to use 2.2 rules for compilation, and `android:installLocation` should be recognized. Then, test your app on 2.1 and 2.2.

Comment: Does this set the min and target sdk in the AndroidManifest through a MOTODEV specific mechanism? I have not used motodev but I would expect the targetSdkVersion to identify the compilation rules that are used, right?

Comment: @Nick Campion: "Does this set the min and target sdk in the AndroidManifest through a MOTODEV specific mechanism?" -- it should touch neither of them, as the build target is independent of anything in `<uses-sdk>`. "I would expect the targetSdkVersion to identify the compilation rules that are used, right?" -- not at all. The build target in Ant is held in `default.properties`, not `<uses-sdk>`. The build target in Eclipse/MOTODEV is held in project properties, not `<uses-sdk>`. `<uses-sdk>` is a runtime thing, not a compile-time thing.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see. The 'magic' done by the android sdk plugins for eclipse seems to have obscured this relationship for me. It seems that changing the project target must fix both places which led me to the incorrect conclusion that they were related. I've deleted my answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot - of course it gave me a warning in the manifest file, but my application worked perfectly with both platforms.

Comment: I might have chosen the wrong emulator yesterday, because today it won't let me choose a 2.1 device for running the project while the target is 2.2. Any idea how to suppress this behaviour?

Comment: @Henrik Christensen: That should not be driven by build target. That should be driven by `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="...">`. Then again, I don't use Eclipse, so I may be applying rationality in an inappropriate place. :-)

Comment: @Henrik Christensen: I want to understand what you're asking here and I'll see if we can help solve it. You are using no feature of 2.2 other than the save to SD card? i.e. No Froyo APIs, right?  You want to test on a 2.1 AVD even though one of your manifest tags is clearly for 2.2?  I know there is intelligence in the plugins to prevent cross-matching of target versions, but I can see where your usage is one of those corner cases that we should consider.

Comment: @Eric Cloninger: Yes, SD card installation is the only Froyo feature I use. As far as I could see on the page i linked to in the edited part of my question, there should be no problem running the application on an Eclair device. However, I'd like to test it on 2.1 to make sure there will be no compications. My manifest file still states `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>` (2.1), all I changed was the build target which I set to 2.2. - "You want to test on a 2.1 AVD even though one of your manifest tags is clearly for 2.2?" - yes, that's exactly what I want to do :)

Comment: [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html#Compatiblity) shows exactly what I've done. Only issue is that it won't allow me to run/debug it on devices with Android 2.1 because it's older than the build target.

Answer (score 0):

So is this bug in eclipse ? When you set build target to higher version then android:minSdkVersion it wont allow you to run on minSdkVersion. This answer is incorrectly  accepted, when it don’t work in Eclipse (that was in question).